# Modeling legacy table with Hibernate and auditing with Javers

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, javers

I'm trying to model with hibernate The following legacy table:

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `child_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`,`child`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id`)
)
```

so each parent would have many children and all his children will have the same `parent_id` but different `child_name`

```
@Entity
Class Parent(
    @Id
    int parent_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Child> childrenList
)

@ValueObject
@Entity
@IdClass(Child.ChildPK.class)
Class Child(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "child")
    String name;

    @ShallowReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Parent parent;
)
```

I would like to achieve auditing when list is changed and the value that changed.
Under this setup, whenever i add a new child, i get two changes:

1. initial change for new child entity(new object)
2. reference change of child list.

but whenever I delete a child, only the childList is audited as list change but no "TERMINAL" for the child entity.

why in some cases its possible to annotate Entites as valueObjects?
how can I achieve auditing when the child is being deleted?(im using spring boot starter)

whenever a child is added or deleted, i get a reference of childrenList, clear it then save the new list.

```
    List<Child> childrenList = parent.getChildrenList();
    childrenList.clear();
    childrenList.addAll(newChildrenList);
```

I would appreciate the following notes:

1. should I annotate Child as valueObject?
   it has an Id and ValueObjects don't have it but I saw example which
   is possible to annotate it as a ValueObject. why?
2. In the "ManyToOne" - should I ignore it?
3. what does is active when ignoring the id field in child besides the auditing? does it affect the javers somehow?